# Solving an equation, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

So I am trying to solve this **[EQUATION](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5%2F4+%28-463%2Bsqrt%281216881-16000+*+68%29%29)** in Python 2.7.3:

```
import math

y = 68
x = -5/4*(-463 + math.sqrt(1216881-16000 * y))
print x
```

x should print **130**, but instead is printing 208.

I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Try: `-5.0/4*(-463 + math.sqrt(1216881-16000 * y))`

Comment: What do you expect `-5/4` to be?  Try it.  You may be surprised.

Comment: @JonathanDavies, I recommend you use `from __future__ import division`, though (simpler transition to python 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that the result of a division of an integer by another integer returns a integer, 
change one of your constants to float and you'll get the correct result

try this:

```
import math

y = 68.0
x = -5/4.0*(-463 + math.sqrt(1216881-16000 * y))
print x
```

for more information please read:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, any idea why? It also works with 5.0/4 also. @Victor

Comment: @JonathanDavies, please read my edit

Answer (score 3):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> -5/4
-2
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> -5/4
-1.25
```

See [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).  Python 2 returns the floor on integer division, Python 3 returns a float where needed.